# Placement of Business Logic in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, business-logic

I want to know where in my code I should place my business logic.  Should it be in my model or should it be in the controller?  I have always thought it should be in the controller but I have been told by a friend that I should put it in the model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Neither - It should be in a separate business object.

Comment: So, how would that be organised?

Comment: This looks to be a decent starter guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En